# KDE applications installed through plasma-discover not showing, must be launched through Software Center

Tags: kubuntu, kde, software-center, paths, discover-software-center

KDE version: **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**

Plasma Discover Version: **5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1**

I rebooted my PC and afterwards, any applications I had previously installed through plasma-discover (https://userbase.kde.org/Discover) no longer show up in the Application Launcher. It should be noted that these applications are still on the machine and when opened, work normally. In order to open the affected applications, I must open the Discover tool, search the application, select it, and select launch. If I want to open a file I can't view/use my normal editors in the 'select application to open with' so I must use the system default of LibreOffice, the other option I have is open up a text editor and then manually path to the file to open it (I guess I can also open it into the correct application with the command line).

Symptoms:

- Searching for these applications in the Application Launcher shows no results.
- If I go to the KDE menu editor, the applications are not shown.
- Applications that are saved to the taskbar can still be opened without needing to navigate through the Application Launcher.
- If I try to select a file and select 'open with' the affected applications are not shown in the list.

Things Tried:

- Uninstalling these applications and reinstalling them does nothing. Newly installed applications also do not appear in any of the previously mentioned menus.
- I have tracked down very few posts (no more than 3 or 4) mentioning a problem that resembles the one I am having, but all of them never reach a conclusion, solutions did not seem to work for me, or the solution made me to weary to try out of concern for doing more damage than good. (I am relatively new to the Linux scene and have been forced to fully reinstall multiple times at this point, I cannot be forced to do so again)
  Through a recent test, I found that if I manually re-add the application to the KDE menu editor, it is possible to re-enable these applications, however this must be done manually for every application I have and every application I will have, but it suggest to me that the source of the problem may have something to do with file paths or permissions (how this could have been broken/corrupted is beyond me as I don't recall doing anything that could lead to such a change). If it is a path issue, I have been unable to phrase a query good enough to find a solution on Google.

A personal request from me is, if there are any commands I should run, **please explain what the command does**. I am here to learn what is wrong as well as how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the ***.desktop** files
from

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications
```

to

```
/usr/share/applications
```

Ex: in my case, install GTK+GUCV View from Discover and have to launch the app via Discover, too. Run this command in Konsole (Terminal if you are using other distros):

```
sudo cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/guvcview_guvcview.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

Now you can access the app via Launcher Menu.
All done!